# Join 2 Tables together with SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a `Customer` and `Customer_2` table which I am trying to join together:

Both tables have data in them, but upon joining with a statement only the column names are being returned without data. I am trying to use the following join statement:

```
select distinct * 
from Customer c 
join Customer_2 d on c.CUST_NUM = d.CUST_NUM
```

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Customer] 
(
    [CUST_NUM] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [CUST_LNAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CUST_FNAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    CUST_BALANCE [MONEY] NOT NULL, 
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [Customer_2]  
(
    [CUST_NUM] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [CUST_LNAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CUST_FNAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL, 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data in each Table:

```
INSERT INTO Customer 
VALUES ('1000', 'Smith', 'Jeanne', '1050.11'),
       ('1001', 'Ortega', 'Juan', '840.92');

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_2 
VALUES ('2000', 'McPherson', 'Anne'),
       ('2001', 'Ortega', 'Juan'),
       ('2002', 'Kowalski', 'Jan'),
       ('2003', 'Chan', 'George');
```

Expected output would be combining customer_2 onto the bottom of the customer table with the extra column `CUST_BALANCE` being 0 or null for each of the four customers on the customer 2 table.

Comment: Could you post sample data, expected & actual results?

Comment: Most importantly if you can't post all data, post data for each table making sure we have at least one cust_num which the same in both tables

Comment: What does the INVOICE table have to do with your question? No idea what the question here as it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I edited the main post with the data and a description with expected output, hopefully it is more clear, thank you. Invoice table is not relevant to this particular question, it is just an inclusion of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you are trying to get a total of the invoice amount for each customer? The easiest way to accomplish this is create a derived table of Customer and Customer_2. I am doing that with a cte in this example. Then it becomes a simple aggregate to get the total.

```
with Customers as
(
    select CUST_NUM
        , CUST_LNAME
        , CUST_FNAME
    from Customer
    UNION ALL
    select CUST_NUM
        , CUST_LNAME
        , CUST_FNAME
    from Customer_2
)

select c.CUST_NUM
    , c.CUST_FNAME
    , c.CUST_LNAME
    , InvoiceTotal = SUM(i.INV_AMOUNT)
from Customers c
left join INVOICE i on i.CUST_NUM = c.CUST_NUM
group by c.CUST_NUM
    , c.CUST_FNAME
    , c.CUST_LNAME
```

Comment: This gives the correct output except for the one entry for Juan  Ortega is duplicated,

Answer (score 1):

I guess whats happening is your join condition is never met meaning both tables aren't having same `cust_name` try to debug as below left join

```
   select distinct * 
   from Customer c 
   Left join Customer_2 d on 
   c.CUST_NUM =
   d.CUST_NUM
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to do what you think it will. This will join every single row in the first table with every single row in the second table when the CUST_NUM isn't the same. It is almost a cross join or cartesian product.

Comment: Check now although the first too had shown some data to OP. I nowhere said it will do the thing which OP wants but definitely it would have shown some data as I already said above as debug

Comment: You posted it as an answer and I suggested it probably wasn't the answer they were looking for. To be fair, the OP is still defining the question. Still not really sure what they are looking for but your answer is a more reasonable guess now.

Comment: @SeanLange agreed mate but without the data i couldnt proceed with editing my answer again as I could see now the OP has added one new condition but that too require some data view

Comment: I tried this and it returned all the data from Customer table, but with the columns cust_num, cust_lname, and cust_fname repeated and showing null entries. for 2 rows, The expected output should be 7 rows total with null listed for the cust_balnace column as there is no cust_balance column on customer_2 table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select c.[CUST_NUM] , c.[CUST_BALANCE]
FROM INVOICE I
JOIN (
     SELECT CUST_NUM, CUST_BALANCE FROM Customer c 
     UNION
     SELECT CUST_NUM, NULL as CUST_BALANCE FROM Customer_2 d
   ) tbl t on i.cust_num = t.cust_num
```

Comment: provide context around your answer to avoid removal.

Comment: I tried to give the answer. Not sure what context you want me to add.